# Attached User profile form gets error on save

Tags: 7, forms

I had attached my user_profile_form in my custom form and called the custom form by the defining a new path in hook_menu(). The user_profile_form got rendered correctly. But while saving the form I'm getting the following error.

```
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
drupal_array_set_nested_value() must be of the type array,
null given, called in /var/www/html/mytheme/includes/form.inc
on line 2655 and defined in drupal_array_set_nested_value()
(line 6746 of /var/www/html/mytheme/includes/common.inc).
```

I used the following code in my form :

```
$form = array();
module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');

global $user;

$form = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user, 'account', 'custom');


unset($form['account']['mail']);
unset($form['account']['current_pass']);
unset($form['account']['pass']);
unset($form['timezone']);
//print '<pre>'; print_r($form);exit;

return $form;
```

Please suggest ideas on resolving this.

Comment: Where do you implement that code?

Comment: In .module file

Comment: Try to implemt it into [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x)